# Статус бар на айфоне

Tags: css, iphone

интересуюсь вопросом. Как настраивается вот этот блок в браузере на айфоне? Надо стили какие то прописать на сайте, или метатеги?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С чего вы взяли что это можно как-то настроить? Это ведь панель телефона

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39749015/1016033 Вот какой-то древний вопрос